# How to pass data from oneviewcontroller to anotherviewcontroller while using swrevealviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

this is my code:

```
   let swswipe:SWRevealViewController=UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("swswipe") as! SWRevealViewController
        if(indexPath.row==0)
        {

           let swipe=swipeView()
            swipe.collectionClick="one"
            self.presentViewController(swswipe, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }



            front
              |
1st view <->swreveal<->2ndview(swipe)
```

i am trying to sent values from 1st to 2nd but intermediate there is  a swrevealview controller is there ,so that value didn't receive

but i didn't receive anything

```
 print("coming to collection view", self.collectionClick)
```

Comment: did you tried delegate pattern?

Comment: no i didn't try delegate pattern ,can you explain me briefly please @ismail

Comment: but i am using collection view while click the cell i need to send the string ...@ismail

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in any of following ways:

- Send a notification when the second controller is going away and have the parent listen for it.
- Create a delegate protocol that lets the second controller reference a parent method directly.
- (If that needs to implement over the back button action)Use the parent's viewWillAppear: and check the isMovingToParentViewController property for whether it's just re-appearing.

and apply what is best for your value passing conditions and availability of values.